# MPAndroidchart click events in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I've hard time to understand how to implement "on slice click" click event .

I'm able to call `pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener()` but have no idea where to go from here.

How can I implement click events on MPAndroidchart  pie chart in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Add listener in your activity or fragment

```
pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)
```

You implement methods

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
    Log.d("PieChart", e?.y.toString())
    Log.d("PieChart", (e as PieEntry).label)
}

override fun onNothingSelected() {

}
```

[image]

**Logcat:**

> D/PieChart: 34.0
>
> D/PieChart: London

Comment: hi @Kasim. I have a chat helper where the piechart is set up. How can we work with click event there.